# Does Cloud Foundry support web sockets?

Tags: websocket, playframework-2.0, cloud-foundry

I have deployed the play framework 2.0's sample websock-chat app onto cloud foundry, but the part after you join the chatroom doesn't display anything. I wondered if this was a websocket support issue, because the app works fine locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, CloudFloundry supports Websockets, thanks to its [gorouter component](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/concepts/architecture/router.html).

Support is also available on the PWS instance, on `wss:` port `4443`, [see official documentation](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/release-notes/).

Comment: Heh. Old question for with I have a working demo that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, it appears according to https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-45, that the answer is no.

Comment: For sure, DotCloud supports Websockets.

Answer (score 2):

Now with latest updates in CFv2 it has a support for websockets (see [this line](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/blob/46f240c7af52eb45f0c0011cd69c1d2be2c8feee/proxy.go#L189) in the code of gorouter, which is responsible for redirecting requests to your apps). I've written a proof-of-concept app in Node.js (for complete example see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17878010/1948038)) and it is working fine for my local CF deployment, so I expect it would work for other frameworks and languages also.

However it is not yet working on https://console.run.pivotal.io/, as I suppose because they are not updating deployment of CF with each commit. Also there are some issues with IE 10 and Firefox (which might be CF issues), but in Chrome it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

if its websockets , then I'll suggest you must go for Jelastic , its easy and reliable.
http://jelastic.com/docs/websockets